# How Sevlet3 login method work?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, authentication

I am trying to authenticate user by Sevlet3 so did this code in Java class

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {

           request.login(user, password);

        } catch (ServletException e) {

}
```

and in Tomcat server.xml file i made this entry

```
<Realm localDataSource="true" debug="99"
                className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionName="hariom"
                connectionPassword="password" connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccc"
                digest="md5" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" roleNameCol=role_name"
                userCredCol="password" userNameCol="email_id"
                userRoleTable="users_list" userTable="user_list_view" />
```

Here in above code `users_list` is database table and `user_list_view` is a database view ..Now i want to know how this code is called and which query fired by login method so that i can check its my issue or i have done some wrong configuration . So how to know which query will be fired and how login method will authenticate user?

Answer (score -1):

The container (the Tomcat server) is in charge of dealing with authentication (using the standard JAAS), you do not have to write any code (well, at most an HTML page to be used to ask the user for the data and pass it to the container, if you are using FORM authentication).

The container will know with security realm to use because it will be defined in a configuration file (not `web.xml`, but each container uses a different one; Tomcat uses `META-INF/context.xml`)

When the authentication data for a webapp is passed to the container, it gets which realm to use from the `context.xml` file and calls the modules from that realm.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Note: J2EE container are powerful, but **complex**. You will save yourself a lot of time reading the manual and, at least, getting an idea of which concerns are managed by them.

Comment: Do you mean what all i am doing is wrong? I did some weired  thing thats why it is not working

Comment: I do not fully understand what you are trying to do. I have explained to you the relationship between the tomcat `server.xml` file and the authentication in your website, if you want to use the container managed authentication (which most of the people would advise to do).

Comment: JAAS has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You haven't provided us with all the information yet. You'll also need to tell us 1) how you have populated the user, password and role information in the database and 2) what values you are passing to the login method.